# funciones dyplr dentro de lapply

Tags: r-dplyr

alguien sabe por que no puedo crear un dataframe con dyplr dentro del lapply, me lo crea vacío. La idea es prefiltrar y la ejecución no se me rentalice tanto con el for

````
Pagos_BCR <- read_excel(ruta_archivo, sheet = "Pagos",col_types = c("text", "text", "date","date", "text", "numeric"))

Pagos_BCR$Fecha_Asociada <- lapply(1:nrow(Pagos_BCR), function(i) {
  print(i)
  expediente_pago <- Pagos_BCR[i, 2]
  print(expediente_pago)
  fecha_pago <- Pagos_BCR[i, 4]
  
#  lista_expedientes <- Orden_Giro%>%
#    filter(Expediente==expediente_pago)
  
  fecha_asociada <- as.Date("1900-01-01")
  for (j in 1:nrow(Orden_Giro)) {
    if(!is.na(Orden_Giro[j, 1]) && !is.na(Orden_Giro[j, 4])&&(Orden_Giro[j,1]==expediente_pago && Orden_Giro[j,4]<fecha_pago)){
      if(Orden_Giro[j,4]>fecha_asociada){
        fecha_asociada <-Orden_Giro[j,4]  
      }
    }
  }    

  print(fecha_asociada)
  return(fecha_asociada)
  
})

# Imprimir el DataFrame actualizado
View(Pagos_BCR) ```
````